# Retrieve method content as an `Expr`ession

Tags: expression, julia

I have a function `f` defined as follows.

```
f(x, y) = 3x^2 + x*y - 2y + 1
```

How can I retrieve the following `quote` block for this method, which includes the function contents?

```
quote  # REPL[0], line 2:
    ((3 * x ^ 2 + x * y) - 2y) + 1
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As folks have mentioned in the comments, digging through the fields of the methods like this isn't a stable or officially supported API.  Further, your simple example is deceiving.  This isn't, in general, representative of the original code you wrote for the method.  It's a simplified intermediate AST representation with single-assignment variables and drastically simplified control flow.  In general, the AST it returns isn't valid top-level Julia code.  It just so happens that for your simple example, it is.

That said, there is a documented way to do this. You can use [`code_lowered()`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/base/#Base.code_lowered) to get access to this intermediate representation without digging through undocumented fields. This will work across Julia versions, but I don't think there are official guarantees on the stability of the intermediate representation yet.  Here's a slightly more complicated example:

```
julia> f(X) = for elt in X; println(elt); end
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> code_lowered(f)[1]
LambdaInfo template for f(X) at REPL[17]:1
:(begin
        nothing
        SSAValue(0) = X
        #temp# = (Base.start)(SSAValue(0))
        4:
        unless !((Base.done)(SSAValue(0),#temp#)) goto 13
        SSAValue(1) = (Base.next)(SSAValue(0),#temp#)
        elt = (Core.getfield)(SSAValue(1),1)
        #temp# = (Core.getfield)(SSAValue(1),2) # line 1:
        (Main.println)(elt)
        11:
        goto 4
        13:
        return
    end)

julia> code_lowered(f)[1] == methods(f).ms[1].lambda_template
true
```

If you *really* want to see the code exactly as it was written, the best way is to use the embedded file and line information and refer to the original source.  Note that this is precisely the manner in which Gallium.jl (Julia's debugger) finds the source to display as it steps through functions. It's undocumented, but you can even access the REPL history for functions defined interactively. [See how Gallium does it through here](https://github.com/Keno/ASTInterpreter.jl/blob/c8e954d91e01ae415e02b37e0e73955c57800012/src/ASTInterpreter.jl#L999-L1032).

Comment: In Julia 1.6, the output of ``code_lowered(f)[1]`` looks different, somewhat more tidy.

Answer (score 0):

First, retrieve the method using `methods(f)`.

```
julia> methods(f)
# 1 method for generic function "f":
f(x, y) at REPL[1]:1

julia> methods(f).ms
1-element Array{Method,1}:
 f(x, y) at REPL[1]:1

julia> method = methods(f).ms[1]
f(x, y) at REPL[1]:1
```

From here, retrieving the `Expr`ession is straightforward; simply use the `lambda_template` attribute of the method.

```
julia> method.lambda_template
LambdaInfo template for f(x, y) at REPL[1]:1
:(begin 
        nothing
        return ((3 * x ^ 2 + x * y) - 2 * y) + 1
    end)
```

---

Edit: This does *not* work in Julia v0.6+!

Comment: This is not safe between versions of Julia.

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas Ooh, I hadn't realized that. Is there a way I could *make* it safe? If not, how could I produce this behavior specifically in v0.6+?

Comment: Not sure how to make this safe. Just for reference, this (and related changes) is [why the debugger Gallium is broken on v0.6](https://github.com/Keno/Gallium.jl/issues/153). Essentially, anything like this that you do not see in the documentation is something that can break between versions without a News article (since it's considered internals). You're at your own risk using pieces of internals like this.

Comment: Getting the AST of a method is not covered by the existing reflection API and there is no way to do it in an officially supported way. You either need to use brittle tricks like this, and manually update as the representation changes, or find some alternative way to solve the root problem.