# surface syntax AST of a method - code_surface?

Tags: julia, abstract-syntax-tree

Is there a way to get the surface syntax AST of a method?

according to the docs http://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/devdocs/reflection/ there is a function/macro for everything below surface AST, starting with `code_lowered` for lowered AST.

it would be great to have something like

```
f(a,b) = 2*a + b
@code_surface f(1,2)
# :(2a + b)
```

where `code_surface` shall return f's definition in form of a standard `Expr` abstract syntax tree.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/julia-users/V4HE008VQPY gives an answer how to get an ``Expr`` AST representation from a code_lowered ``LambdaInfo`` ``c``:
"""Base.uncompressed_ast(c) gives the AST (Expr object), and Base.lambdainfo_slotnames(c) gives the argument names`"""
However this is not the "standard" AST apparently, but lowered.

Comment: This is kinda/sorta a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/42520913/176071.  See my last paragraph there, though — the un-lowered syntax isn't saved with the method definition, so the best way to get it is to refer back to the source file.

Answer (score 1):

`@code_expr` from [CodeTracking.jl](https://github.com/timholy/CodeTracking.jl) returns the `Expr` of the method definition (needs the Revise.jl package to also be installed).

```
julia> f(a,b) = 2*a + b
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> using CodeTracking

julia> @code_expr f(1, 2)
:(f(a, b) = begin
          #= REPL[65]:1 =#
          2a + b
      end)

julia> @code_string f(1, 2)
"f(a,b) = 2*a + b"
```

(There was [discussion](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/2625#top) about adding a similar feature to base Julia, but it seems unlikely to happen at this point.)

Having the LHS of the method definition in the result helps with knowing which method was applied to the given arguments

```
julia> f(a::String,b::String) = a * b
f (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> @code_expr f("hi", " friend")
:(f(a::String, b::String) = begin
          #= REPL[74]:1 =#
          a * b
      end)

julia> @code_expr f(2, 5)
:(f(a, b) = begin
          #= REPL[65]:1 =#
          2a + b
      end)
```

But if you only need the `Expr` of the function body, you can extract that part of the expression from the result (`ex = @code_expr(f(2, 5)); ex.args[2]`).